# Adicionar Conta em Array e Exibir as informações em uma Table

Tags: javascript, html5

Podem me ajudar com um código?
Preciso que insira informações em dois `Array` diferentes através de duas mensagens `prompt` sempre que o botão "Adicionar Conta" seja acionado e, assim que o botão "Mostrar contas" for acionado, mostrar todas as contas em uma tabela com o número da conta (nCad), o nome e o valor na conta. Meu código não funciona da forma que eu gostaria.

```js
var nomeA = new array[''];
var account = new array[''];
var nCad = new array[''];
var cadastro = 0;

function addAccount(){
  cadastro++;
  nomeA.push = prompt("Nome: ");
  account.push = prompt("Conta: ");
  nCad.push = cadastro;
}

function showAccounts(){
info.innerHTML("<table>");

for(x=0; x=cadastro; x++){
  info.innerHTML("<tr>");
  info.innerHTML("<td>" + nCad[x] + "</td>");
  info.innerHTML("<td>" + nomeA[x] + "</td>");
  info.innerHTML("<td>" + account[x] + "</td>");
  info.innerHTML("</tr>");
info.innerHTML("</table>");
}
```

```css
td{
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="addAccount()">Adicionar Conta</button>
<button onclick="showAccounts()">Mostrar Contas</button>
<div id="info"></div>
```

Comment: Oi Gabriel, falta um `}` na função `showAccounts`. Sabes isso ou é esse o teu problema?

Answer (score 0):

Tens alguns erros no teu código:

- falta um `}` na função `showAccounts`
- para inserir HTML deves usar `.innerHTML = 'string'`, e não `.innerHTML('string')`, isso seria mais parecido com jQuery
- para inserir elementos numa array deves usar `.push(elemento)`, e não `.push = elemento`

Refiz o teu código, removi o `nCad` e `cadastro` pois tendo uma array sabes sempre o seu `.length` ou seja o numero de elementos. No caso do meu exemplo através do indice iterado pelo `reduce`.

```js
const info = document.getElementById('info');

const clients = [];
const account = [];

function addAccount() {
  clients.push({
    name: prompt("Nome: "),
    account: prompt("Conta: ")
  });
}

function showAccounts() {
  const rows = clients.reduce((html, client, i) => {
    return `
      <tr>
        <td>${i+1}</td>
        <td>${client.name}</td>
        <td>${client.account}</td>
      </tr>
    `;
  }, '');
  info.innerHTML = `<table>${rows}</table>`;
}
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="addAccount()">Adicionar Conta</button>
<button onclick="showAccounts()">Mostrar Contas</button>
<div id="info"></div>
```

Comment: Sim, @Sergio, dessa forma ele funciona bem em quesito geral, porém na tabela aparecem apenas com o a última conta inserida, estou tentando usar o loop do for conforme o 'Lenght' do tamanho do Array de Clientes para criar a tabela com todos os dados.

Comment: @GabrielVeiga já tens uma array com clientes? podes colocar aqui ou na pergunta? e queres ainda ter o `prompt` ou isso foi só para a pergunta?

Answer (score 0):

```
const clients = [];
const account = [];

function addAccount(){
   clients.push({
   name: prompt("Nome: "),
   account: prompt("Conta: ")
 });
}

function showAccounts(){
   info.innerHTML = '<table>';

   for(x=0; x=clients.length; x++){
      info.innerHTML = '<td>' + clientes.lenght +'<td>';
      info.innerHTML = '<td>' + name[x] + '</td>';
      info.innerHTML = '<td>' + account[x] + '</td>';
      info.innerHTML = '</tr>';
   }
   info.innerHTML = '</table>';
}
```